# How to remove leading zeros with on mm:ss ggplot axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a plot of seconds vs another variable. I want the y axis label to appear as MM:SS format. With scale_y_time it is showing up as HH:MM:SS.

```
dat = data.frame(y = c(215.29,217.73,220.06,227.97,225.46,231.65,247.92,254.6,265.03,280.05,283.68),
                 x = c(21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11))

ggplot(data=dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    scale_y_time()
```

[image: Example plot]

In the linked example image the label shows as 00:04:30, I want 4:30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_y_time(labels = function(i) substring(i, 5))
```

But I would point out that :

- this is ambiguous without further labelling *e.g.* 4:30 could mean 4.5 hours
- A leading zero for minutes is better if values for minutes can equal or exceed 10 (in which case use `substring(i, 4`)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. In the context that I am using this for, it will be clear that I mean minutes without the additional labeling.

Comment: `scale_*_time` coerces everything by adding `scales::hms_trans`. While `format.hms` is pretty useless, `as.POSIXct.hms` will let you use `format.POSIXct`, which allows further reformatting when implemented similarly, e.g. `scale_y_time(labels = function(x) format(as.POSIXct(x), format = '%M:%S'))`